# Can I make git bisect display shortened commit SHAs?

Tags: git, git-bisect

Running `git bisect` generates output like this after each bisection:

```
Bisecting: 22 revisions left to test after this (roughly 5 steps)
[123fedacc728b985d4f8d010e2a69dcbdcbf3e8e] use binascii module for hex/binary conversions
```

Can I make it use partial commit name prefixes, similar to those used in `git log --abbrev-commit`? Something like this:

```
Bisecting: 22 revisions left to test after this (roughly 5 steps)
[123feda] use binascii module for hex/binary conversions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The [source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/bisect.c#L905) for `git bisect` allots memory for a full hash and a terminator. It'd probably be easy to patch in a flag, however. You might try sending one to the git list if you think it's a worthy addition to git.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the link though, will try to resist the urge to add git to my list of things I'm hacking. :)